# How to edit an XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an assignment due to monday, but I am stuck with one task. I have to be able to edit an xml with different set of data. My xml looks like this which I want to edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfAutokategorie xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Autokategorie id="8">
    <name>145265478</name>
    <feeByDay>1000</feeByDay>
    <feeByWeek>14444</feeByWeek>
    <car>
      <string>HALOOOO</string>
    </car>
  </Autokategorie>
  <Autokategorie id="11">
    <name>147</name>
    <feeByDay>52</feeByDay>
    <feeByWeek>369</feeByWeek>
    <car>
      <string>HALOOOO</string>
    </car>
  </Autokategorie>
</ArrayOfAutokategorie>
```

My code to edit looks like this:

```
public bool update(){
    string filepath = "category.xml";
                XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
                serializerHelper shelper = new serializerHelper();
                List<Autokategorie> klist = shelper.showData(typeof(List<Autokategorie>), filepath) as List<Autokategorie>;
    
                Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben Sie die Id der Kategorie ein die Sie bearbeiten möchten");
                showCategories();
                Console.WriteLine("Id: ");
                string idInput = Console.ReadLine();
    
    
    
                foreach(var id in klist)
                {
                    if (id.id.Equals(int.Parse(idInput)))
                    {
                        bool inputTester = true;
                        while (inputTester)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Welche Seiner Daten möchten Sie verändern? ");
                            Console.WriteLine("Sie können jederzeit durch das drücken der 4 die Bearbeitung beenden und zurück ins Kategorie Menü gelangen");
                            Console.WriteLine("1) Für Namen");
                            Console.WriteLine("2) Für Preis pro Tag");
                            Console.WriteLine("3) für Preis pro Woche");
    
    
                            Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben Sie nun eine Option ein");
    
                            switch (Console.ReadLine())
                            {
                                case "1":
    
                                    var tgt = xDoc.Root.Descendants("Autokategorie").Where(x =>
                                      x.Attribute("id").Value.Equals(idInput));
    
                                    var name = xDoc.Descendants("name").FirstOrDefault();
                                    Console.WriteLine("Alter Name: " + name.Value);
                                    Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben sie den neuen Vornamen ein");
                                    name.Value = Console.ReadLine();
                                    xDoc.Save(filepath);
                                    Console.WriteLine("Kategorie Name gespeichert als: " + name.Value);
                                    Console.WriteLine("Drücken sie 1 wenn Sie weitere Daten bearbeiten möchten, oder die 4 um zurück ins Hauptkategorie Menu zu gelangen.");
    
    
                                    if (Console.ReadLine().Equals(1))
                                    {
    
                                        break;
    
                                    }
                                    continue;
    
              }
    
                        }
                    }
    
                   
    
    
                }
```

My problem is that no mater what I type as id be it 8 or 11 only the data of the first set (id = 8) is changed. I can not seem to find why. I really am desperate right now.

Here are two additional Methods as information first is save method the other one my XMlserialization:

saveMethod:

```
public bool saveCategory()

        {
            string filePath = "category.xml";
            serializerHelper sHelper = new serializerHelper();
            List<Autokategorie> categoryList = new List<Autokategorie>();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben sie den Namen der Kategorie!");
            string categoryNameInput = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben Sie die Tages Leihgebühr!");
            double feeByDay = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben Sie die Wöchentliche Leihgebühr!");
            double feeByWeek = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Clear();


            if (File.Exists("category.xml"))
            {
                categoryList = sHelper.showData(typeof(List<Autokategorie>), filePath) as List<Autokategorie>;

            }
            categoryList = sHelper.showData(typeof(List<Autokategorie>), filePath) as List<Autokategorie>;
            var idSetter = new Random();

            int id = idSetter.Next(1, 20);
            car = carSelector();

            
            Autokategorie category = new Autokategorie(id, categoryNameInput, feeByDay, feeByWeek, car);

            categoryList.Add(category);

            sHelper.XmlSerialize(typeof(List<Autokategorie>), categoryList, filePath);
            Console.WriteLine("Ihr Kategorie wurde gespeichert danke für die Zusammenarbeit!");

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Drücken Sie 1 um ins Hauptmenü zu gelangen und auf 2 um die Applikation zu beenden!");
            Program p = new Program();


            switch (Console.ReadLine())
            {
                case "1": Program.menuPoints(); return true;
                case "2": Environment.Exit(0); return true;

            }
            return true;
        }
```

Xmlserialization:

```
 public void XmlSerialize(Type data, object objectData, string fileName)
        {
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create)) 
            {
                XmlSerializer xSerializer = new XmlSerializer(data);
                xSerializer.Serialize(fileStream, objectData);
                fileStream.Close();
                
            }
        
        }
```

Comment: Are you required to use `XDocument`?

Comment: No not at all the most important thing is to use serialization and deserialization to save/create and show the data. Everything else is open for us to decide

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to use `<string>HALOOOO</string>` since `string` is a reserved word in C#. Did your instructor provide the XML or did you create it?

Comment: No it was created by me with the file.Create in my serialization. I did not call it string either. It came automatically probably bevause <car> is an string array.

Comment: Use a dictionary to get the element :             XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<int, XElement> dict = doc.Descendants("Autokategorie")
                .GroupBy(x => (int)x.Attribute("id"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

Comment: With your code change From :  var name = xDoc.Descendants("name").FirstOrDefault();  To :  var name = tgt.Descendants("name").FirstOrDefault();  I changed xDoc to tgt.

Comment: THank you it finally worked :)